# passing additional arguments for `createOptFlow_DualTVL1` for Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv3.0, opticalflow

I am trying to use `createOptFlow_DualTVL1` from OpenCV for Python. I am using this book (Page 120) as a reference( https://books.google.de/books?id=TrZTDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=cv2.createOptFlow_DualTVL1()+parameters+python&source=bl&ots=3sQlqNwhDX&sig=h7Ve4FzpsVJKkjrNXpy8t_Arpvw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicu6_EveTbAhUDb1AKHQp1Bq8Q6AEIUDAD#v=onepage&q=cv2.createOptFlow_DualTVL1()%20parameters%20python&f=false).

According to the book, I need to create an instance of `cv2.DualTVL1OpticalFlow` class by calling the `cv2.createOptFlow_DualTVL1` function. Then the optical flow can be calculated by calling the calc function of the created instance. This function takes the previous frame, the current frame and the optical flow initialisations as arguments. The book also says that other algorithm parameters can be set by using set. But I am unable to pass any other parameter as argument in Python. Is there a way to set additional algorithm parameters? Below is a snippet of what I have until now.

`optical_flow = cv2.createOptFlow_DualTVL1()
 flow = optical_flow.calc(new_prvs, new_nxt, None)`

Answer (score 0):

I  found the solution: [here](https://github.com/Rhythmblue/i3d_finetune/issues/2)

For cv2 version "'4.1.0'":

replace:

```
optical_flow = cv2.createOptFlow_DualTVL1()
flow = optical_flow.calc(new_prvs, new_nxt, None)
```

with:

```
optical_flow = cv2.optflow.DualTVL1OpticalFlow_create()
flow = optical_flow.calc(prvs, next, None)
```

The parameter descriptions can be found here: http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/d47/classcv_1_1DualTVL1OpticalFlow.html